# start hadoop failed with hadoop-functions.sh

Tags: hadoop

I tried to start hadoop, but it failed with nothing started. Following the console log.

```
Mac:sbin lqs2$ sh start-all.sh
/Users/lqs2/Library/hadoop-3.1.1/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: 
syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/Users/lqs2/Library/hadoop-3.1.1/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: 
`done < <(for text in "${input[@]}"; do'
/Users/lqs2/Library/hadoop-3.1.1/libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 70: 
hadoop_deprecate_envvar: command not found
/Users/lqs2/Library/hadoop-3.1.1/libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 87: 
hadoop_bootstrap: command not found
/Users/lqs2/Library/hadoop-3.1.1/libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 104: 
hadoop_parse_args: command not found
/Users/lqs2/Library/hadoop-3.1.1/libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 105: 
shift: : numeric argument required
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as lqs2 in 10 
seconds.
WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
```

I have tried any ways to solve it but nothing woked. Even I reinstalled the latest version. But the error is the same. It almost drives me mad.

Any answer is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Please show your entire install process from start to finish. For example, which Java, which environment variables, which config files, etc

Comment: Sorry, here is the environment varibles
     JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Ho me                   
     HADOOP_HOME=/Users/lqs2/Library/hadoop-3.1.1   
     SPARK_HOME=/Users/lqs2/Library/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all information I asked for. Also your Hadoop XML files, please

Comment: In your Java home... Does `Contents/Ho me` actually have a space?

Comment: Also, Spark doesn't support Hadoop 3 yet, I believe.. You've downloaded Hadoop 2.7 version of Spark https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18673

Comment: Thank you the same. It's nice of you. I have solved the problem by the answer next. It seems that the problem lies in the way I start hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop scripts require bash, not sh

```
$ chmod +x start-all.sh
$ ./start-all.sh
```

Though I would suggest starting HDFS and YARN separately so that you can isolate other issues

You also need to downgrade Hadoop to at least the latest 2.7 release for Spark to work

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. It works! It's nice and good of you. I have searched for a answer for a whole day.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was seeing this error in OSX after installing Hadoop using HomeBrew. The solution was to do a fresh install after downloading the Hadoop (3.2.1) binary directly from the official website. While installing, I had set HADOOP_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables.

A word of caution: I found that the issue can occur if the following environment variables are defined in hadoop-env.sh :

```
export HDFS_NAMENODE_USER="root"
export HDFS_DATANODE_USER="root"
export HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER="root"
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_USER="root"
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_USER="root"
```

I had initially added these variables while trying to fix the issue. Ultimately I removed them and the error disappeared.

Note, I executed all the Hadoop commands and scripts as non-root user, and also upgraded bash to version 5.0.17.

Comment: I removed also these variables and it works